# How can I search and display Integer in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to search integer and display results in datagridview

here is my Form.design

[image]

And Here is my code

```cs
 private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lastNameQuery = from player in dbContext.Players
                                where player.PlayerID.StartsWith(formTextBox.Text)
                                orderby player.LastName, player.FirstName
                                select player;

            playersBindingSource.DataSource = lastNameQuery.ToList();

            playersBindingSource.MoveFirst();
            bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Enabled = false;

        }
```

I think `StartsWith` is the problem, that method is for the string. But, I couldn't find the proper method for searching Integer.

Comment: Instead of treating PlayerID as a string try to convert the content of the textbox to an integer, then search for equals

Comment: *"I think StartsWith is problem"* - Is that the logic you want to use?  Are you searching for a string or a number?  Do you want to match any number that "starts with" the input or that "equals" the input?  Is it *currently* successfully getting values which "start with" the input?  What specifically are you looking to change or asking us?

Comment: I want to search number. When I searched Lastname with Startswith, It got values. But I don't know how to search a number(player ID)